# Neo4j Cypher: How to stop duplicate SET if multiple CREATES

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a complex cypher query that creates multiple nodes and increments some counters on those nodes. For sake of example here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
START a = node(1), e = node(2)
CREATE a-[r1]->(b {})-[r2]->(c {}), e-[r3]->b-[r4]->(d{})
SET a.first=a.first+1, e.second=e.second+1
RETURN b
```

The issue is that because there are two CREATE commands the SET commands run twice and the values are incremented by 2 instead of 1 as intended. I have looked to see if I can merge the multiple CREATE statements and I cannot.

My initial idea is to separate out the different creates into a batch query, however I was wondering if there is another option.

Comment: You are missing relationship-types in your query. I only get a count of 1 for the two creates. Perhaps you should show your real query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you executing this query? What version of neo4j are you using?

I went to [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org/) and successfully ran the following and it correctly added one to both a.first and e.second:

```
START a = node(1), e = node(2) 
CREATE a-[r:KNOWS]->b-[r2:KNOWS]->c, e-[:KNOWS]->b-[:KNOWS]->d 
SET a.first=a.first+1, e.second=e.second+1 
RETURN b
```

Comment: I was running this query against Neo4j 2.0 M03. I have since upgraded to M04 and my tests are now failing. I'm not sure what caused the problem in the first place but it is working now.